# ZSH - PATH Duplication : Directory added at end of PATH keeps duplicating when re-opening Terminal Session

Tags: path, duplicate

I have recently installed PIPX on MAC running Big Sur and ZSH shell. During the install it prompted for the following to be added to the `.zshrc` file....

```
# Created by `pipx` on 2021-03-20 14:22:23
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/xxxx/.local/bin"
eval "$(register-python-argcomplete pipx)"
```

Running echo `$PATH` showed `/Users/xxxx/.local/bin` added to the end of my PATH variable. However, when I close the terminal and open up a new session, running echo `$PATH` now shows the location duplicated at the end of the PATH `:/Users/xxxx/.local/bin:/Users/xxxx/.local/bin`

Opening and closing new terminal sessions doesn't seem to create any more additions to PATH it just remains at these 2 entries....

I have run `typeset -U PATH path` to remove the duplicate but each time I open up new terminal sessions it just duplicates again.

Does anybody know how I can stop this from happening.....I would really like to keep my PATH variable as clean as possible.

Comment: Did you try removing the `export PATH=...` all together and see if you end up with just one?  Are you sure you don't already have a similar line in your file?

Comment: Try from a subshell and see if it duplicates in any further. Try couple of subshells in fact. You may have to put thr path declaration in .profile and log out and login once.

Comment: Try running `zsh --login --xtrace` to see where the path is added twice. BTW, you may want to replace the first line with `path+=( ~/.local/bin )`

Comment: Thank you for your advice.....@Andy Dalton, yes I did end up with just one......@Just Khaithang, it did not duplicate further when opening sub shells.....@ Stephane Chazelas, I ran 'zsh --login --xtrace'....wow, I had not run that before, it generated too much info to review !!!  I have now found the source of the problem....I have amended my main post to reflect.  @Stephane - why change to `path+=( ~/.local/bin )` ....what is the benefit of that ?

Comment: `path+=( ~/.local/bin )` avoids hardcoding the path of your home directory, and if `$PATH` was previously empty makes it `PATH=/Users/xxxx/.local/bin` instead of `PATH=:/Users/xxxx/.local/bin` (which you wouldn't want to do as that puts the current working directory at the head of the PATH search).

Comment: thankfully I was adding /.local/bin to the end of an already populated `PATH`.....so my 'PATH` starts with 'PATH=/' not `$PATH=:/` (so how would i write the path += statement into an export instruction, would it be `export PATH+="$PATH:~/.local/bin"`

Answer (score 0):

I have now found the source of duplication.  Whilst during the install of pipx it requested that I add the stated directory to the path to the .zshrc file.  However, it appears that somehow it also automatically added the export path statement to the .zprofile file.

Now I just need to decide if there is any value leaving it on both files or removing it from one of them.